# word usage of 'improves' vs 'provides'

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Can I say

> *something* **improves** employment opportunities to *somebody*

when expressing

> *something* **provides more** employment opportunities to *somebody*

If it's correct to say **improves employment opportunities**, is it better than using **provides** as stated in my question? Is there a difference?

Comment: Hi, Grace, what is something? Can you provide more context where the sentences would be used? I posted an answer and realized that choosing the right verb could depend on your context. I deleted my post.

Comment: So long as your "something" is a *noun* or a *noun phrase*, I like it.

Comment: @Rathony I wanted express that bilingual education provides more employment opportunities for socially and economically disadvantaged students. A friend advised me to use the word 'improve' but will this expression indicate that I think some jobs are superior than others? (My friend is sleeping and we don't share the same time zone, so I asked this question on ell)

Comment: Hi Grace - you may want to edit your question to include the information in your comment. I think it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Industries *provide* employment opportunities. Education *increases* employment opportunities. *Improves* is not used as often in this context.

[image]

Do you mean educational opportunities *while* bring educated or educational opportunities *as a result* of being educated?

If you mean the first one, use *provides*, and if you mean the second one, use *increases*:

> Bilingual education increases employment opportunities for socially and economically disadvantaged students

Compare

> Education is an important tool that increases employment opportunities for women.

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=5hfKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&dq=education+%22increases+employment+opportunities%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEor6qjaTKAhVHXh4KHTUwAXsQ6AEITDAH#v=onepage&q=education%20%22increases%20employment%20opportunities%22&f=false)

See the related Google search for [education "increases employment opportunities"](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&biw=360&bih=228&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=nNmUVvCxOoTMepWrqMgH&q=education+%22increases+employment+opportunities%22+&oq=education+%22increases+employment+opportunities%22+&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...8686.22495.0.23635.5.5.0.0.0.0.987.2572.0j2j0j1j6-2.5.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..5.0.0.jZsoNWR5jKo).

**In sum**, if you mean that bilingual education leads to higher job participation rates (more people getting jobs), then either *increases* or *improves* is fine. The former is more common. Using *improves* in this context can refer only to job quantities (the number of jobs available to people). It does not have to imply that some jobs are better than others. However, to move further away from this implication, use *increases*.

*{This answer written by a native speaker of American English and teacher of ESL/EFL}*

Comment: Considering the OP's context, it is not wrong to use "improve employment opportunities". See [NgramViewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=improve+employment+opportunities%2C+increase+employment+opportunities&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimprove%20employment%20opportunities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincrease%20employment%20opportunities%3B%2Cc0) and type in [education "improves employment opportunites" and you will get a lot of results. I actually posted similar answer, but changed my post.

Comment: "Improves opportunities" has a different connotation to me than "increases opportunities" - one is raising the overall quality of the opportunities, the other is changing how many opportunities there are. Lowering my salary expectations would increase my job opportunities. Learning a trade would improve my job opportunities. Granted, most folks aren't as precise in their language as I tend to be.

Comment: @ColleenV so you prefer to use the word 'improve', right? I think this word is good but I'm a little bit concerned that this expression would indicate that I think some jobs are superior than others

Comment: @ColleenV Do you disagree that  Getting training, learning a trade, getting an education *increase* employment opportunities?

Comment: @GoDucks after reading you comments, I think 'increase' is a good alternative. but I am not sure which one is more apt here...

Comment: @Grace, if you mean that bilingual education leads to higher job participation rates (more people getting jobs), then either *increases* or *improves* is fine. The former is more common. Using *improves* in this context can refer only to job quantities (the number of jobs available to people). It does not have to imply that some jobs are better than others. However, to move further away from this implication, use *increases*.

Comment: @GoDucks What I don't understand from your comment is this. If improve only refers to the job quantities, what's the difference between to increase and to improve? There is no difference. Why aren't they interchangeable? What ColleenV commented above seems to be reasonable. To improve is more related with "quality" than "quantity".

Comment: @GraceGao I don't prefer one or the other for your sentence - it depends on what you would like to say. I just wanted to point out that increases and improves aren't interchangeable the way that I use them in that context.

Comment: Here is an example article where "improves" indicates the quality of the jobs: http://www.dol.gov/newsroom/releases/eta/eta20151264 "A good job gives a person a sense of dignity and purpose, and creates a path to the middle class. Returning citizens deserve a second chance and an opportunity to find a good job," said U.S. Secretary of Labor Thomas E. Perez.